# Why asymmetrical current limiting on ESD Diodes?

Tags: esd

I was reading this:

https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/esd-diodes-as-voltage-clamps.html

And came by this:
[image]
[image]
Why would anyone choose the configuration in Figure 1, which limits current for negative spikes but not positive ones, over Figure 2?

Comment: The use that topology again in Fig. 7.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, but but that doesn't shed any light. In fact, it just raises the question even more since they just end up using an enormous resistor that swamps out the 400 Ohms and makes it behave essentially symmetrically.

Comment: Reading it more, they require an external R to be added.  In their example calculation it came to be 100k, so the additional 400ohms is nothing.

Comment: @Aaron Like...is it something about actually fabricating it on a silicon wafer that makes it more convenient to have a resistor separating the two diodes rather than having end-to-end diodes? That's literally the only reason I can think of it but it feels like a stretch.

Comment: Agreed.  The 400ohms could be left out, unless it's part of some feedback that they are not showing for simplicity?

Comment: oops, I missed that the area inside the dotted lines are inside the chip.

Comment: I think DKNguyen is on the right direction. But the point of the two cases are well-explained in the article. If you use the device in Figure 1, you will NEED to add external current-limiting resistors to cover the case where the input pins may rise too high and the only thing handing it is the diode (which cannot handle more than a small amount.) In the device in Figure 2, you may not need to do that. The differences between them, though, is probably due to substrate issues.

Comment: Here are two partially-researched guesses, but I haven't completed the research and I really should get back to work. 1) Maybe the topology of Figure 1 works to better prevent SCR-based latchup, since the two diodes form a P-N-P-N structure (i.e. an SCR), and the resistor could mitigate this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up  [Note: this one feels incorrect, since the bias would be in the wrong direction.] 2) Perhaps it's just an intrinsic part of that lower protection diode, as seen in Figure 1 in this app note: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-339.pdfJP.pdf